# Creating file with advanced name using Batch

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, filenames

I'm trying to use a batch script to create a file like following:

```
echo ping %ip% -t -l %psize1% >%n%_%psize1%.bat
```

- `%n%` (name) stated in other areas correctly and `%psize1%` (package size)
- if `%n%` is `test` and `%psize1%` is `10` then the file should look like `test_10.bat`

However it creates `_10.bat` file and leaves the `%n%` statement completely out.

```
@echo off
mode 128.64
title DOS Creator 2.0
color 07

:wrapper
cls
echo --------------------------------------------------------
echo    Welcome To Ping check By Raoul
echo --------------------------------------------------------
echo.

pause

:menu
cls
echo -----------------------------------------
echo - 1. Guide
echo - 2. Target Information
echo - 3. Parameters
echo - 4. Exectution Parameters
echo - 5. Final Check
echo - 6. Exit
echo -----------------------------------------
set /p option="Option : "

If "%option%" == "" (
echo PLASE STATE ANNY OF THE ABOVE NAMED OPTIONS
pause
Goto :menu
) else if "%option%" == "1" (
goto :Guide
) else if "%option%" == "2" (
goto :info
) else if "%option%" == "3" (
goto :end
)

:Guide
cls
echo this is still WIP
pause
goto :menu

:info
cls
set /p ip=Ip Host:
set /p fname=File Name:
pause
cls
echo The Following has been stated:
echo IP:----------------"%ip%"
echo File Name:---------"%fname%"
echo.
set /p option="Is this correct? (y/n) : "
if "%option%" == "y" goto :Parameters

goto :Target

:Parameters
cls
echo.
set /p psize1=Package size file 1:
echo.
set /p option="Ready to create files? (y/n) : "
if "%option%" == "y" Goto :Creator

goto :Parameters

:Creator
echo ping %ip% -t -l %psize1% >%n% %psize1%.bat
cls 
echo --------------------------------------------------------
echo The following files have been created with info:
echo Target IP -"%ip%"- Package size for file 1 -%psize1%-
echo --------------------------------------------------------
echo.

pause
```

Comment: Are you changing `n` variable inside a `for`-loop? I don't see anything wrong with the code so I suggest you add more relevant code to the question.

Comment: I agree with wOxxOm, please put here the complete batchfile, so that we can have a look whether or not the value of n is assigned or changed during the course of the batchfile.

Comment: How does one add code? it messes up the spacing and lines..

Comment: mark it and press the `{ }` Icon.

Comment: can't locate, where `%n%` is being set. Should it be `%fname%`?

Comment: You do never set variable `n`, so `%n%` expands to an empty string, of course...

Comment: Yhea... Cant belive i've overseen that.. Thank you! Sometimes you just need to step away and comeback later because spending long time into lines of coding just makes you imume to stupid mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

You do never set variable n, so %n% expands to an empty string, of course... – aschipfl

Anwser is check variables if they are correct and stated. In my case i forgot to change n to Fname.